# Partition With Offset

Tags: partitions

I have the following two lists:

{a,b,c,d,e,f} and {x,y,z}

and would like to use Partition to create groups of the form:

{a,x}, {b,y}, {c, z}

My first approach is to use:

```
list1 = {a,b,c,d,e}
list2 = {x,y,z}
flat = Flatten[{list1, list2}]
```

The output of which is a single list that I intended to use Parition to create the list of pairs.

So, if I try Partition

```
Partition[flat, 2, 5}
```

The result is: {{a, b}, {x, y}}

Not the desired result, but I can't find the right parameters of Partition to generate the correct list of pairs.

I can drop the the final elements of list1 based on the length of list2 and then use Transpose.

Just curious if Partition can get to the same result.

Comment: Are you aware of this? `Flatten[{{a, b, c, d, e, f} , {x, y, z}}, {2}]`

Answer (score 7):

I think a solution using *solely* [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) does not exist, but with [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d, e};
list2 = {x, y, z};
flat = Flatten[{list1, list2}];

Partition[flat, 3, 5]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
> ```

Or [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
Partition[flat, 6, 1][[All, {1, -1}]]
```

> ```
> {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
> ```

Perhaps [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) is of interest too:

```
list1 ~Riffle~ list2 ~Partition~ 2
```

> ```
> {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}, {d, x}}
> ```

And [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) has a ragged form:

```
Flatten[{list1, list2}, {2}]

% // Cases[{_, _}]
```

> ```
> {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}, {d}, {e}}
>
> {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
> ```